# How to make v-switch mandatory in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have three `v-switch` with values. each of them is bind to `switch1` property.

When I click on the `v-switch` is remove/add value to `switch1`.

How to do `v-switch` mandatory? meaning its impossible to uncheck all. at least one must be selected.

I think some event like if switch1 will be array of empty then cancel the switch click.

I try to do this with change event but I `e` come as Boolean and not the event.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      switch1: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
      change: (e) => { console.log({ e })}
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="px-0" fluid>
      {{ switch1 }}
      <v-switch
        v-model="switch1"
        label="val1"
        value="val1"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switch1"
        label="val2"
        value="val2"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switch1"
        label="val3"
        value="val3"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a **watcher**, and if none of the switches are **true**, then **set the first one to true**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      switch1: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: (e) => {
      /*console.log({
        e
      })*/
    }
  },
  watch: {
    switch1(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal.length) {
        this.switch1 = newVal
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => this.switch1 = oldVal)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="px-0" fluid>
      {{ switch1 }}
      <v-switch v-model="switch1" label="val1" value="val1" @change="change($event)"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="switch1" label="val2" value="val2" @change="change($event)"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="switch1" label="val3" value="val3" @change="change($event)"></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The other thing is that I wouldn't put `@change` event in **data** - I think they are better placed in the **methods**.

## EDIT

I updated the snippet to offer a more general solution. Thanks for the `setTimeout(() => this.switch1 = oldVal)` comment @JonSud!

Comment: Nice! I just changed to `else setTimeout(() => this.switch1 = oldVal)`

Comment: Yeah, that may be better for a more general case :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly answer the question, but is an option to validate a section of switches and incorporating an error message when no switches are active.

This is accomplished by having an Array of switch values, `switches`, which tracks the state of each switch.

Within a computed property, `noneSelected`, we can filter the Array's values based on overall truthiness. When the length of the filtered Array is zero (0) we display the error message via `v-if` targeting the computed value.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      switches: [false, false, false]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    noneSelected() {
      return this.switches.filter(x => !!x).length === 0;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: (e) => { console.log('event', e)}
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="px-0" fluid>
      {{ switches }}
      <p v-if="noneSelected" style="color: red">At least one switch needs to be active.</p>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switches[0]"
        label="val1"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switches[1]"
        label="val2"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switches[2]"
        label="val3"
        @change="change($event)"
      ></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```